# simple Debounce not working in react 16 but works in jsfiddle with react 14.3

Tags: reactjs, debouncing

This doesn't work in react 16, but this jsfiddle works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/kp04015o/9/

Can any one debug this error why? Cannot read property 'value' of null, at  handleChange = debounce(e => this.setState({searchTerm: e.target.value}), 1000);

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const debounce = (cb, wait) => {
  let timeout;

  return function() {
    let callback = () => cb.apply(this, arguments);

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(callback, wait);
  }
}

class Debounce extends React.Component {
  state = {
    searchTerm: '',
  };

  handleChange = debounce(e => this.setState({searchTerm: e.target.value}), 1000);

 render() {
   return (
     <div>
       <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
       <div>Search Value 2: {this.state.searchTerm}</div>
     </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Debounce />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about [Event Pooling](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#event-pooling)

Here you have a working code:

```
class Debounce extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  state = {
    searchTerm: '',
  };

  setSearchTerm = debounce((searchTerm) => this.setState({ searchTerm }), 1000);

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <div>Search Value 2: {this.state.searchTerm}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

or nicer with ES7 decorators and `decko` module: 
    import { debounce, bind } from 'decko';

```
class Debounce extends React.Component {
  state = {
    searchTerm: '',
  };

  @debounce(1000)
  setSearchTerm(searchTerm) {
    this.setState({ searchTerm });
  }

  @bind
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <div>Search Value 2: {this.state.searchTerm}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. And also the event pooling link was helpful. Also I believe it's better to use a simple debounce function like I mentioned rather than a module for footprint reasons? I'm keeping the debounce function in an util folder and importing that instead of any library.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I know this.

Try changing this:

```
<input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

to either:

```
<input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />
```

or:

```
<input type="text" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)} />
```

That is my gut reaction every time I see something of undefined with a React event, and because your default state is handled. If this works, it's because the execution context or lexical environment is in a different dimension than it might appear.